# Get maximum value in paspark, insert it and drop duplicates

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I stuck in solving my problem.

What I have:
Pyspark dataframe that looks like:

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | country | counter |
+====+=========+=========+
|  A |      RU |       1 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  B |      EN |       2 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  A |      IQ |       1 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  C |      RU |       3 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  D |      FR |       5 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  B |      FR |       5 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

I need to take max value of country  by counter (or any if equal) and delete all duplicates. 
So it should looks like:

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | country | counter |
+====+=========+=========+
|  A |      RU |       1 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  C |      RU |       3 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  D |      FR |       5 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  B |      FR |       5 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried? Could you provide a sample dataframe with `df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'B', ....], 'country': ['RU', 'EN', ....], 'counter': [1, 2,...]})`?

Comment: @MachineLearner it is not pandas dataframe. I work with pyspark dataframe I took from cassandra database.

Comment: I didn't understand your use case, because in sample output when you have taking A, RU, 1 then why you did not take A, IQ, 1. Is it based on ID or some other column?

Comment: maybe, for each "id" you need row with biggest "counter"?

Answer (score 1):

You can first `drop duplicates` based on `id` and `counter` , then take `max` over a window of `id` , finally filter where `counter` equals the Maximum value;

If order of `id` is to be retained , we would need a monototically increasing id to be assigned so we can sort later:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window.partitionBy('id')

out =(df.withColumn('idx',F.monotonically_increasing_id())
        .drop_duplicates(['id','counter'])
        .withColumn("Maximum",F.max(F.col("counter"))
        .over(w)).filter("counter==Maximum").orderBy('idx')
        .drop(*['idx','Maximum']))
```

---

```
out.show()

+---+-------+-------+
| id|country|counter|
+---+-------+-------+
|  A|     RU|      1|
|  C|     RU|      3|
|  D|     FR|      5|
|  B|     FR|      5|
+---+-------+-------+
```

If order of `id` is not a concern , same logic but no additional id required:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window.partitionBy('id')
out1 = (df.drop_duplicates(['id','counter']).withColumn("Maximum",F.max(F.col("counter"))
                                     .over(w)).filter("counter==Maximum")
                                     .drop('Maximum'))
```

---

```
out1.show()

+---+-------+-------+
| id|country|counter|
+---+-------+-------+
|  B|     FR|      5|
|  D|     FR|      5|
|  C|     RU|      3|
|  A|     RU|      1|
+---+-------+-------+
```